# Why doesn't Bump Node work?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, bump

Trying to create a decay effect but nothing happens when I connect the bump node to the principled bsdf. Why?[image]

Comment: Connect the texture to the _Height_ input of the Bump Node - not the _Strength_.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that is the correct answer. I cant however mark it as "correct answer" since you posted it as a comment

Comment: There - I made it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the texture to the *Height* input of the Bump Node - not the *Strength*.:

[image: Bump]

However, given the way Bump nodes work (by default), the difference between black and white is 1M  - looks strange when trying to emulate on the surface of something at full strength (especially when bump maps are generally used to convey minor surface ripples/imperfections). The easiest remedy I've found is to mix the Noise Texture output with some greyscale value (I used white in the example, but that may change depending on your use case) quite heavily (my mix is at .998). You can see the difference especially in shiny metallic things (pictured below):

[image: Soften]